# How to read a scalar value returned from a stored procedure. IEnumerable<int?>

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have a stored procedure which returns `maxNum`. I can see the return value in the debugger: `maxNum[0]` has the value. I saw it in the debugger.

```
IEnumerable<int?> maxNum = DB.uspGetNextTestNumber();
```

How to read the value from it.

The above code is calling a stored procedure from ADO.NET Entity model. 
ASP.NET MVC. VS2013. Windows 8.1 64 bit.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetNextTestNumber]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT MAX(testnumber) + 1 as NextNumber
    FROM [ProductTesting].[dbo].[PtTest] AS sp  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable maxNum = DB.uspGetNextTestNumber();

```
        List<int?> lst = maxNum.ToList<int?>();

        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            if (item.HasValue)
            {
                string str = item.Value.ToString();

                // str has the value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy when `using System.Linq`:

```
int? number = DB.uspGetNextTestNumber().FirstOrDefault();
```